# Installing MATLAB Ubuntu 12.10, persistent "permission denied" problem

Tags: 64-bit, matlab

I'm trying to install MATLAB on Ubuntu 12.10, I had it in my last laptop with 12.04 and I didn't have much trouble to install it.

I'm getting this problem:

```
j@jgb:~/Programs/Instaladores/matlab$ ./install
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
./install: 1: eval: /tmp/mathworks_1436/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Permission denied
Finished
```

And it doesn't change if I change the permissions to the java file or to the install file as other posts say.

In my /etc/fstab file I had this line added (But nothing changes if I comment it):
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noexec,mode=1777 0 0

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried installing the MATLAB R2012b.

The problem was the login name. Make sure you write the correct login name during the installation process, and its **case sensitive**.

I deleted the files and re-installed it and it worked.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't give the install program permission to write the file /tmp/mathworks_1436/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java

Try:

```
sudo install
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the x permission to the "java" file

see ! it's easy ;)

http://tylau0.blogspot.com/2011/12/matlab-linux-install-error.html

Comment: He's not trying to execute the java file, the installer is trying to write it.

Comment: I got the same problem before and adding the x permission helped me. The install program needs to execute some java commands.

Comment: take a look: http://tylau0.blogspot.com/2011/12/matlab-linux-install-error.html